# C# Twitter - Upload Image - No 3rd party Libraries

Tags: c#, twitter

I have a library that I wrote a while ago that allows me to post a new status to Twitter.  So handling of the OAuth headers etc is all working.

However, I now have a requirement to upload an image using the Twitter REST API:

```
https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json
```

When posting a status I normally put the following in the request stream `'status=<my tweet here>'`

Ideally I want to post the raw image data rather than a Base64 string, however, I am having issues with each of them working.

According to Twitter, the OAuth should only be build up from the keys starting 'oauth_' - I am only putting the following in:

```
parameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey);
parameters.Add("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
parameters.Add("oauth_timestamp", Base.Methods.UNIXTimestamp);
parameters.Add("oauth_nonce", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""));
parameters.Add("oauth_version", "1.0");
parameters.Add("oauth_token", token);
```

Twitter says that when in doubt to use a content type of `application/octet-stream` - when doing this, I get a response of:

```
Code: 38
Message: Missing Parameter Media
```

In fact, I also get the same response when setting the content type to `multipart/form-data` as suggested in other pages from Twitter

I have tried various combinations of add the image data to the webrequest, and all seem to fail.

```
media=<my image byte data here>
Add header of 'media' with image data in the request
```

and as many other combinations I can think of.  I even get the same issues when trying to send the Base64 version (which I'd rather not do).

Having read through lots of other questions I don't seem to be able to see what I am doing wrong.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, and it all comes down to the content being sent in the request stream.

As twitter says, only send in the `oauth_xxxx` parameters, the content based ones are not needed for this request.

The trick is the building up of the multipart form, I have done the following:

1. I am using an HttpWebrequest, so set it up to send the multipart form headers:

   ```
   string boundary = "----" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString("x");
   webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
   ```
2. Build the content to be sent, which has both a prefix and a suffix to the actual image data

   ```
   StringBuilder prefixData = new StringBuilder();
   prefixData.Append("--");
   prefixData.Append(boundary);
   prefixData.Append(Environment.NewLine);
   prefixData.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"");
   prefixData.Append(Environment.NewLine);
   prefixData.Append(Environment.NewLine);
   byte[] prefix = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(prefixData.ToString());

   StringBuilder suffixData = new StringBuilder();
   suffixData.Append(Environment.NewLine);
   suffixData.Append("--");
   suffixData.Append(boundary);
   suffixData.Append("--");
   byte[] suffix = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(suffixData.ToString());
   ```
3. Join each of the data sections together to post to the stream:

   ```
   byte[] data = new byte[prefix.Length + imageData.LongLength + suffix.Length];
   Buffer.BlockCopy(prefix, 0, data, 0, prefix.Length);
   Buffer.BlockCopy(imageData, 0, data, prefix.Length, imageData.Length);
   Buffer.BlockCopy(suffix, 0, data, prefix.Length + imageData.Length, suffix.Length);
   ```
4. Write the data to the request stream as normal.